# JavaFX TabPane title OverrunStyle

Tags: java, javafx

I have a `TabPane` like below,

[image]

I want the text to be **clipped** at close button, similar to how browsers display the title like below.

[image]

I have tried **css**,  `-fx-text-overrun : clip;` in `.tab-pane` and `.tab` class but not working as expected.

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: the selector to set the text propertie for the tabs is .tab-label - but that doesn't help: the headers (aka: label) are layouted according to their pref width which is not affected by clipping, and that's done in an internal class which is deeply buried inside TabPaneSkin, no way to change afaics.

Comment: I don't believe there's an [`OverrunStyle`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/OverrunStyle.html) for having a "fading clip". I don't know how browsers do it, but it could possibly be mimicked by having the close button's background set to a linear gradient that fades to transparency on the left (and have the close button cover the label). However, the `.tab-close-button` is a `StackPane` with its `shape` set, so setting its background just sets the color of the `x`. Might need an entirely custom skin to work around that.

Comment: You can get some idea in this question.<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922138/how-to-set-tab-name-size-in-javafx?answertab=votes#tab-top>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to achieve the required L&F by setting the `Label` preferred width.

[image]

```
.tab-label {
    -fx-pref-width : 150px;
}
```